# test transaction call brownie

Tags: testing, brownie, calldata, unittesting

in brownie, i have a function that calls another one in the same contract, and i want to test if it does it properly :

**The function :**

```
function onTokenTransfer(
    address _sender,
    uint256 _fee,
    bytes calldata _data
) public {
    require(_fee >= fee, "NOT ENOUGH FUNDS");
    bytes memory data = _data[4:];
    uint256 _id = abi.decode(data, (uint256));
    Collab memory collab = collabById[_id];
    require(
        _sender == collab.promoter,
        "Only promoter can call this function"
    );
    withdrawEther(_id);
}
```

**The test :**

```
def test_on_token_transfer_calls_withdraw_ether(
      link, paid_promotion, account
    ):
     # arrange
     id = 0
     
     # act
     tx = link.transferAndCall(
         paid_promotion,
         Web3.toWei(0.1, "ether"),
         paid_promotion.withdrawEther.encode_input(id),
         {"from": account},
        )

# assert
assert // how can i assert that onTokenTransfer called withdrawEther .
```

**My question :** how can i assert that onTokenTransfer called withdrawEther ?